# Why does a drive appear to have more free space than its capacity, even though a large amount of space is taken?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, hard-drive, btrfs, dolphin

I have a 3 TB (2.7 TiB) hard drive attached to my system, which is formatted as Btrfs.

As can be seen in the screenshot, there are files on the hard drive totaling 709.6 GiB (bottom part of the screenshot). However, the Dolphin file manager reports on the bottom right that there is 2.9 TiB of free space on the drive.

[image: 2.7 TiB hard drive, reports 2.9 TiB free, even though 709.6 GiB of space is taken]

Why does Dolphin report more free space on the drive than the drive's capacity, even when a large portion of the space is taken up by files?

Does it have something to do with the nature of the Btrfs file system?

Using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.